# Using a clickable div to submit a simple_form in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I've got this div that I'd like to be able to click on to submit a simple_form in Rails 4.

```
<div id="submit-form" class="bottom-nav-box" style="width: 66.6%;">
  <div class="center-wrapper">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="bottom-nav-box-content" style="float: right">
        <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The idea is that I want to get the "submit-form" div to submit the form when clicked, rather than have a tiny button in the middle of it that says 'Submit'.

I was thinking something along the lines of wrapping the entire thing in `<%= link_to f.submit do %>` but that doesn't work at all.

Is there any way I can do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best using Javascript for this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#submit-form", function() {
   $("#form").submit();
});
```

The caveat here is that you'll need a valid HTML form (as demonstrated below) which you can invoke the "submit" function for:

```
#view
<%= form_tag your_path do %>
   <%= ... tags ... %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

--

You must remember that Rails is back-end; JS is front-end. You can't call "front end" functionality with Rails directly (its exactly the same as PHP) - you'll have to use JS to bind events in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) to any event you wish to call on the backend

You must also be aware that Rails' primary task is to render HTML on the front-end. In the backend, it will do all the amazing ruby-based magic; but the front-end only renders HTML. This means you have to ensure you're able to send the required data / functionality within the confines of the [HTML spec](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)